# git push на два сервера

Tags: git, git-push, push

Ситуация такова, что у меня есть ДОМАШНИЙ сервер, с установленным гит и апачем.
на нем хранится репозиторий и хуком развертывается на веб-морду.

Требуется хранить его копию на bitbucket, github.

добавил в конфиг

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = garmayev@server.dev:/var/git/*******.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "bitbucket"]
    url = ssh://git@bitbucket.org/garmayev/*******.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Вопрос: можно ли как-то автоматизировать push на два сервера? Т.е. чтобы не вводить каждый раз

`git push origin`

`git push bitbucket`

а ввести один раз git push и усе. На данный момент на последнюю команду реп пушится только на origin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте так

1. `git remote | xargs -L1 git push`

   Получить через команду `remote` список удаленных репозиториев, и
   вызвать для каждой команду `push`
2. Для облегчения ввода такой длинной команды, можно завести [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).

   `git config --global alias.pushall '!git remote | xargs -L1 git push'`

   После этого, можно вместо длинной команды набирать

   `git pushall`

   `"!"` - символ используется, если мы вызываем некую внешнюю команду, которая не является подкомандой git(в нашем случае, это подкоманда является вызов команды git). В указанной ссылке в самом внизу страницы есть пояснение использования этого символа при создании алиасов.

Comment: Объясните адиету, что делает данная команда `!git remote | xargs -L1 git push`?

Comment: `git config --global alias.pushall '!git remote | xargs -L1 git push'`

По этой команде в конфиг вбилось только '!git

вправил в блокноте всю строку, теперь выдает сообщение
`Expansion of alias 'pushall' failed; '~git remote | xargs -L1 git push' is not git command`

Что делать?

Comment: По какому пути смотрели глобальный конфиг? После выполнения этой команды, там должно быть написано `pushall = !git remote | xargs -L1 git push`. Никаких правок в блокноте делать не нужно. У вас в конфиге такая строчка записалась? Символ `!` не упустили? Судя по ошибке, упустили.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. В процессе правки данную команду выделил кавычками (сам не знаю зачем и почему :) ). Сейчас все работает! Спасибо!